# Is there a simple way to use the Facebook c# sdk?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am looking for startup samples using the Facebook C# sdk. I have found the sdk and a lot of different samples but written for mvc. My hope is to find something using aspx-files, configuration in the web.config and of course the dll:s with the sdk. I would like to retrieve information and to post information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of the Facebook API in C#. It shows fetching posts for a particular Search term:

```
public class Post
    {
        private string id;

        public string Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }
        private string created_time;

        public string Created_time
        {
            get { return created_time; }
            set { created_time = value; }
        }
        private string message;

        public string Message
        {
            get { return message; }
            set { message = value; }
        }
    }

public class FacebookHelpers
    {
        private const string PUBLIC_POSTS = "/search";
        public List<Post> SearchPosts(Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
        {
            List<Post> postsList = new List<Post>();
            try
            {
                var app = new FacebookAPI();
                dynamic result = app.Get(PUBLIC_POSTS, parameters);


                foreach (dynamic item in result.Dictionary["data"].Array)
                {

                    if (item.Dictionary.ContainsKey("message"))
                    {

                        List<JSONObject> valueList = new List<JSONObject>(item.Dictionary.Values);

                        Post p = new Post();
                        p.Message = valueList[0].String;
                        p.Id = valueList[1].String;
                        p.Created_time = valueList[2].String;
                        postsList.Add(p);

                    }
                }
                return postsList;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
                return postsList;
            }


        }

public List<Post> SearchPosts(string searchTerm, string until = "today", uint maxRecords = 100)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            parameters.Add("q", searchTerm);
            parameters.Add("type", "post");
            parameters.Add("until", until);
            parameters.Add("fields", "message");
            parameters.Add("limit", Convert.ToString(maxRecords));

            return SearchPosts(parameters);
        }
    }
```

You would require the FacebookAPI.dll and NewtonSoftJson.dll. I hope this is of some use to you. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks, I have used the Facebook C# sdk, I guess this is another one. Is the FacebookAPI.dll new? Is someone developing, updating? :)